# Remove dropdown options performance issue

Tags: jquery, performance, html-select

I need to know the fastest way to remove hundreds of options from a dropdown list.

Right now, Firefox is really slow at updating my 2nd drop down dynamic list.
Chrome is doing OK with the script but I need to speed up my removal of:

```
<select id="myDropDown" name="myDropDown">
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=2>2</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
<option value=4>4</option>
<option value=5>5</option>
... all the way to let's say 500
</select>
```

Repopulating it is a breeze. I have a json parser that creates the
    `<option></option>`
fields.

I've tried:

```
.remove()
.children().remove()   
.empty()
```

They all have the same sluggish performance in removal of hundreds of options.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: How are you deciding which elements to remove? It would likely be faster to work out which elements you need to populate the `select` with, rather than populate it and then work out which to remove.

Comment: I want all of the <option> elements removed between the <select></select> field item.  It's getting updated with new data from an ajax json call.  So each time field A is changed, field B gets changed.  So wipe out what's in field B then repopulate from the ajax json call.

Comment: Oddly, and I realise it's a minimal example with nothing else on the page, but a `select` element, containing 2339 `option`s, can be emptied more or less instantaneously: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Mq9nd/). Could you post a link to a live demo reproducing your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looping through them?

```
$('#myDropDown option').each(function(i, option){ $(option).remove(); });
```

You can specify which ones by keeping track of the value of `i`.

Comment: Yeah that would work if I wanted to keep track of what they chose.  Which I don't want to.  Bascially think of it like a State/City combo.  If I choose California, I'll get every city in California in the 2nd drop down (potentially hundreds).  Now if I change California to say, Alaska, I would need to remove all of California's cities and replace with Alaska's cities.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I think that if you want it to be really fast, you could just show/hide the options

```
$("#someOption").hide();
```

**EDIT:**
I think you may have an array of values that have to populate, let's say `values`. It'd be fast if you traverse your options first and check for each one if it's in the `values` array (not vice versa, would be slow). So having:

```
var values = [...]; //Array with values that must 'exist' in the dropdown
$("#select1 option").each(function(i, option){
   option.style.display = ($.inArray(option.value, values) >= 0 ? 'block' : 'none');
});
```

Note that we're avoiding jquery selectors inside the loop to boost performance. We are not traversing the array first (and options inside) because searching in an array is much faster than searching an element (option in this case) with a specific attribute (value in this case) in the dom.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that jQuery attempts to cleanup when removing things, read [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) for details (starting with "To avoid memory leaks...").

If you think that this isn't a problem in your situation, then

```
$("#someOption").text("");
```

may be the sledgehammer you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myDropDown").find("option").remove();
```